# 3D Interpolation of randomly arranged coordinate value

Tags: c#, r, algorithm, interpolation

In a .NET/C# project I have relativley randomly arranged coordinates and assigned a weight KPI to each one of them like this:

```
Weight   | Lat       | Long
---------+-----------+-----------
1,123444 | 54,219367 | 9,696117
1,067940 | 51,950265 | 11,692274
1,054050 | 52,131392 | 13,216249
1,044820 | 52,636704 | 9,845077
1,023757 | 50,118346 | 7,308953
1,006427 | 53,612651 | 12,429595
1,002610 | 51,433237 | 7,661594
0,988619 | 49,396423 | 7,022961
0,955858 | 51,010989 | 10,845346
0,943669 | 50,652052 | 9,162438
0,938015 | 51,104541 | 13,201738
0,863415 | 48,790447 | 11,497889
0,835913 | 48,661604 | 9,350134
```

I am not an expert when it comes to mathematics or statistics. What I need to do is to interpolate any other given geo-coordinates weight based on the previously calculated ones (see above).

All the 3D-interpolation algorithms I found assume that the coordinates would have to be arranged in kind of a rectangular shape which is not possible in my szenario.

Are there any algorithms which would fit my need? It might be helpful to point out, that we are using a bit of R.NET funktionality in the same project, so a solution using R would be perfectly fine.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you want to interpolate, the weight or the coordinates? Can you give an example to clarify?

Comment: @sorin instead read 'weight' as 'height' of a surface at the given latitude/longitudes; then, assuming the surface is 'smooth' (in some sense), obtain the height at an arbitrary new latlong. Is this what you mean, nozzleman?

Comment: @AakasahM yeah, I want to give the algorithm new coordinated (lat/long) and receive the interpolated weight. Sorry if that was unclear!

Comment: @sorin, Aakasa is right, see my comment.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860171/interpolate-points-on-a-height-map) covers you, unless I'm missing something

Comment: (see also https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html for another approach)

Comment: @AakashM, your comments basically brought me closest to the solution I now have implemented. If you want to provide your suggestions as an answer, I would gladly accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different methods to do interpolation and they give you slightly different results. You should try a couple and see what works best for your scenario.

One way to do it is take all the data points on a certain radius. Compute the distance to each, then compute a weighted average of their heights using he distance as the weight. This will allow you to interpolate linearly between the points.

If you want something a bit more wavy you can do the same but instead of using distance as weight, you use distance^2 or distance^3. This will give more weight to the closest point and make the surface more curved. You can even combine them to have something like `a*distance^2 + b*distance` but I would keep it as simple as possible.

If you don't want to use a radius because of uneven distribution, you can take the closest K points (experiment with K and see what works best).

These are all very generic but they work relatively well in a lot of cases.

Note: you can compute distance in 3D space if the points are relatively close, but if they are far away you should compute the distance over the sphere (the length of the arc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Abstractly spoken, i was wondering if there is any way to get the 3 nearest points which form a triangle around the given coordinate and calculate the weighed average of those. Are you aware of such an algorithm?

Comment: @nozzleman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search , but unless your points are somewhat uniformly distributed you could find cases where you have more then 3 points at similar distance. That's why I suggested all the points in a radius.

Comment: took some time ;)