# Exploring an algorithm to approximate minimum N concentration of an area

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, geometry

Imagine there is a farmer growing a large land. I have a device to measure the amount of N (Nitrogen) in a location of this land. Using this device I have measured the N values of several locations and I have coordinates of each location.

The problem is I need an algorithm to

- approximate the coordinates of the location where the N value is minimum.
- approximate the N value of that location

Here is the class for keeping Measurement values. It includes coordinates and the corresponding N value of the location.

```
public class Measurement {
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private double N;

    public Measurement(double latitude, double longitude, double n) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        N = n;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public double getN() {
        return N;
    }
}
```

Here is the Main.java class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Measurement> measurements = new ArrayList<>();
        //following data is not real.
        measurements.add(new Measurement(4.1214,5.3445,4));
        measurements.add(new Measurement(4.1224,5.3431,10));
        measurements.add(new Measurement(4.1220,5.3450,15));
        measurements.add(new Measurement(4.121,5.3440,1));
        measurements.add(new Measurement(4.1211,5.3437,4));
        measurements.add(new Measurement(4.1215,5.3475,24));

        Measurement approximated = findMinimumConcentrationLocation(measurements);
    }

    private static Measurement findMinimumConcentrationLocation(ArrayList<Measurement> measurements) {
        //TODO : implement this

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is a real practical problem I got when doing a project (mobile app), not homework or an assignment.

Edit: Assume the area that I need to find the minimum concentration of N is like the convex hull polygon. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-set-1-jarviss-algorithm-or-wrapping/).I am going to get measurements from around the border, and the middle of the area so we can assume that the convex hull gives the target area.

Also, assume that the land is fully horizontal.

I don't want the measurement with minimum values. It will be inaccurate in most cases.

Comment: “approximate the coordinates of the location where the N value is minimum” … within what area?  I imagine the other side of the planet would have the minimum concentration.

Comment: The lowest actual known concentration will always be the point with the lowest measurement, but how accurate do you want to be? How far apart are measurements likely to be taken? What happens when the lowest measurement is surrounded by much higher measurements, but there is a cluster or low measurements over a larger area elsewhere that may be a better location? In theory we can cast a bunch of rays from higher measurements through points with lower measurements and and work out where the end of the lines with the biggest difference over distance intersect?

Comment: @sorifiend I don't need the point with the lowest measurement. I need it to be accurate more than taking the lowest measurement. Can you explain this a little bit more? "In theory we can cast a bunch of rays from higher measurements through points with lower measurements and and work out where the end of the lines with the biggest difference over distance intersect?"

Comment: This might be quite helpful instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860171/interpolate-points-on-a-height-map and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022036/3d-interpolation-of-randomly-arranged-coordinate-value note that you will find a lot more help by looking at examples from the GIS field about dealing with terrain heights and height maps etc because the same logic applies

Comment: Another thought on this. I don't much about Nitrogen and soil seepage, but presumably, Nitrogen will seep through soil especially when aided by water and terrain characteristics like ground slope etc? So you really need more data if you want any degree of accuracy to find your point, otherwise, the GIS and height map algorithm/solutions may very well give a lot of false results.